# Putting a concatenate inside of a count if

Tags: excel, concatenation, excel-formula, countif

Alright, I have two excel functions that work. I want to combine them into one.
Here are the two that work:

`=COUNTIF('ALL EE Active BEG PERIOD'!$A:$B, 'HC Summary Details'!$A6)`

`=CONCATENATE('ALL EE Active BEG PERIOD'!A2," --- ",'ALL EE Active BEG PERIOD'!B2)`

I thought that maybe I could combine them as follows, but it's not working - where am I going wrong?

`=COUNTIF(CONCATENATE('ALL EE Active BEG PERIOD'!A2,' --- ','ALL EE Active BEG PERIOD'!B2)),'HC Summary Details'!$A6)`

Comment: The problem is that `COUNTIF`'s first argument should be a range. By concatenating the contents of two strings that's no longer true - it's a string. It would be helpful to know a bit more about what you are doing. If it's really just a one-to-one comparison, you could do `=CONCATENATE('ALL EE Active BEG PERIOD'!A2," --- ",'ALL EE Active BEG PERIOD'!B2) ='HC Summary Details'!$A6`, but I imagine you want something more complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part of a `COUNTIF` has to be a range, whereas you have a single text value with `CONCATENATE`... Unfortunately, it doesn't seem as if `COUNTIF` can handle arrays either, since I would have suggested `=COUNTIF(CONCATENATE('ALL EE Active BEG PERIOD'!A:A,' --- ','ALL EE Active BEG PERIOD'!B:B)),'HC Summary Details'!$A6)`

Anyway, there's another way of doing this, you can use `SUMPRODUCT` and and `IF` with `CONCATENATE`:

`=SUMPRODUCT(IF(CONCATENATE('ALL EE Active BEG PERIOD'!A:A," --- ",'ALL EE Active BEG PERIOD'!B:B)='HC Summary Details'!$A6,1,0))`

After you typed that, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to get the desired result.

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone will return you the value of the first term in the result array, which you don't want.

What this does is check whether the concatenate matches what is found in A6 of the other sheet, if yes, give `1`, otherwise `0`. `SUMPRODUCT` adds all the those `1` and `0` together.

Comment: That works, but is there a way to make it less manual? In other words, is there a way that I wouldn't have to select each cell and then do the ctrl + shift + enter?

Comment: @user1475816 Once you have done it through Ctrl+Shift+Enter, you can drag it down and it should be working for the others like it did for the first.

Answer (score 1):

If you concatenate the range parameters into a string in another cell e.g. `X1`, and use `COUNTIF(INDIRECT(X1),value)` it seems that `COUNTIF` accepts the string as a range.